# Write a query to find the full names of customers who have rented sci-fi movies more than 2 times and arrange alphabetically

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to answer the above question, but my output varies from from the expected output. My code is as can be seen below,

```
select distinct concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as Customer_name
from customer c
inner join rental r on r.customer_id = c.customer_id
inner join inventory i on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
inner join film f on f.film_id = i.film_id
inner join film_category fc on fc.film_id = f.film_id
inner join category ca on ca.category_id = fc.category_id
where name = 'sci-fi' and rental_id > 2
order by Customer_name
```

[image: mys]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate by customer name and then assert a count of 2 or greater from a `HAVING` clause:

```
select concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as Customer_name
from customer c
inner join rental r on r.customer_id = c.customer_id
inner join inventory i on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
inner join film f on f.film_id = i.film_id
inner join film_category fc on fc.film_id = f.film_id
inner join category ca on ca.category_id = fc.category_id
where name = 'sci-fi' and rental_id > 2
group by Customer_name
having count(*) > 2
order by Customer_name;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, the having clause is throwing me an Error 1064. Any idea how that can be corrected?

Comment: @CodeJunkie Typo in my answer.  Please reload the page and try it again.